# Showing poll results in place of the poll area

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to show the results from a poll in the same area and page as the poll question without reloading the entire page. I am able to get the results and show them in a new page but I do not know how to replace the html in where I have the question and replace it with the html with the results.

**HTML** (with the poll question)

```
<div id="poll-area">
    <!-- Voting poll -->
    <fieldset>
        <form action="javascript:void(0);" id="pollid" name="myform" method="POST">
            <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="left" id="option_left" />Yes</label>
            <label><input type="radio" name="answer" value="right" id="option_right" />No</label>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Vote" />
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="pollid" />
        </form>
    </fieldset>
    <!-- End voting poll -->
</div>
```

**AJAX** call to handle the poll:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($j) {
    $j("form").submit(function(){
        var str = $j(this).serialize();
        $j.ajax({
            url: "poll_vote.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: str,
            cache: false,

            success: function(result) {
                window.location.replace("poll_results.php");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

I am guessing it is instead of the *window.location.replace("poll_results.php")* that I want to replace the HTML within the #poll-area with the #poll-area in the poll_results.php, but I do not know how do it.

**HTML** for the poll results (what is contained in poll_results.php)

```
<div id="poll-area">
   <fieldset>
       <legend>Results</legend>
       <ul>
           <li>
               <span class="total-votes">Yes</span>
               <br />
               <div class="results-bar" style="width:52%;">
                 52%
               </div>
           </li>
           <li>
               <span class="total-votes">No</span>
               <div class="results-bar right-bar" style="width:48%;">
                 48%
               </div>
           </li>
           <li>
       </ul>
       <p>Total votes: 100</p>
   </fieldset>
</div>
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the output of **poll_results.php** you can remove the outer div with the id "poll-area". You don't want duplicate IDs when it is pulled into your current page.

For your jQuery, this should do the trick:

```
success: function(result) {
    $j("#poll-area").html(result);
```

As I'm aware, anything that currently exiits inside the poll-area div will be overwritten with the result from the ajax query. (The voting options should disappear, and the results will be shown)

*Edit (summary of comments):* `poll_vote.php` should output the HTML contained within `poll_results.php`

Comment: thanks.  But the thing is that the results HTML is a bit different than that of the #poll-area with the question.  But is this would work that would be awesome!

Comment: How do I call the poll_results.php file in the jQuery and what should I be returning to 'result'?  Thanks, this ia great.

Comment: If you echo the poll-results at the end of "poll_vote.php" you will see instant results - if you want to test before then a simple echo "thanks for voting"; will demonstrate what happens here

Comment: Ah yes, I can echo the vote results, but how I do change the HTML structure to show the result bars?

Comment: would it be possible to `include("poll_results.php");` at the end of `poll_vote.php`? - you really only want the important html that is inside `<div id="poll-area">`, so no <html><body><style> etc...

Answer (score 1):

Easiest but not the cleanest: use innerhtml and getElementById()

You will get something like:

```
var div = getElementById('poll-area'); //The poll itself
div.innerHtml = getElementbyId('answers'); //The answers
```

Note that I used 'answers' as ID, since you use the same ID for the answers and the poll. So you will get a nested  which will not work. Give your first child of the answers () a new id called 'answers'.

If you know more of javascript, use the createElement to add a new element. This will improve speed and is better, but a bit more advanced.

Comment: thanks, I am going to look into the createElement.  Can I create a new element and replace that new element into the #poll-area? Also, I do not see where I used the same ID for the answers and the poll.

Comment: Yes, shouldn't be a problem. Try the code I gave you and replace the 'answers' in the second getElementById function to 'poll-area' and run your page an watch the errors. There will be a nested <div id="poll-area"> because you are changing the INNER HTML with a div that has the same id. So you will get duplicate IDs ;)

Comment: thanks, I see how this works.  However, would doing this just show the vote count after the voting? How would I show the result bars?

Comment: Like the same. Or append a new element to your dom and insert the bars over there :) Or just do a innerHtml, but as said before. It's not the cleanest solution, it's best to add a new element to the dom and fill it with another command (I'm not that pro with JS), it's better/quicker and you can use it with css instantly because your dom will be refreshed (not the right term, but you will understand what I/JS means by that)